# Is it recommended to put a function inside .each()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I am looping through a collection of DOM elements. Each iteration makes use of a `helper()` function several times like so:

```
$(".myclass").each(function() {
    var arg;
    helper();
    // do stuff
    function helper() {
        // do helpful stuff with arg
    }
});
```

Is it bad practice to include the `helper()` function inside the `function()` block as above? Should I use:

```
$(".myclass").each(function() {
    var arg;
    helper(arg);
    // do stuff
});
function helper(arg) {
    // do helpful stuff with arg
}
```

In the first example will every matched `.myclass` element have its own instance of the `helper` function in memory?

**Edit**: If anyone is looking for a good explanation of the answer - http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/stop-nesting-functions-but-not-all-of-them/

Comment: it's not good for reusability - if you want to use that helper function elsewhere, it only exists in the scope of the callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that will redeclare the function over and over again (every time the loop runs).

You can either put the function in a higher scope like in your second example, or if you want to keep the scope cleaner, you could do a closure around the function (though there are implications of this in terms of when the outer closure gets executed, how many times it gets executed and so on):

```
$(...).each((function() {

    var helper = function(arg) {
        //do helpful stuff with arg
    }

    return function() {
        var arg;
        helper(arg);
        //do stuff
    };

}());
```

Note though that this still has the potential for helper to be defined more than once just not on every iteration.

Answer (score 3):

You do create an instance of your `helper` function in the first example, whereas in the second one there is only one instance used for all iterations.

So to avoid creating multiple identical functions, you may either inline the code in the first example or use the second approach.